# Is pogo oscillation a risk in hybrid motors?

Tags: propulsion, engine-design, hybrid-rocket

Is [pogo oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_oscillation) accounted for in design of [hybrid motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine)? I'm thinking particularly about hybrids that use Nitrous Oxide as the oxidizer because the [weird triple point effects](http://www.bu.edu/rocket/files/2010/02/The-physics-of-nitrous-oxide.pdf) that one experiences with nitrous.

So, do hybrid designers ever have to consider pogo? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking an expert at my work, the answer is that it's not a strong risk for hybrids.  The reasoning is that pogo is typically due to an interaction between a pump and a long vertical run of tubing on a rocket (like where a propellant line goes from the top tank around or through the bottom tank to get to the engine).  Since hybrids only have a single liquid tank there typically are not long vertical runs of piping and most hybrids don't use pumps.